# Java applet connected to database and html

Tags: java, html, database, applet

I work with Eclipse. My applet is connected to a database (a local one for the time being). The name of the applet class is ProjetApplet.class and uses 4 other classes and several jar archives. The problems I have are:

- How to integrate my applet in an html file (the HTML code to do it
  please) knowing that there are several classes and several jars.
- When I was a single class applet it normally appears in my browser, everything works but I got an error message when I tried to access to my database or send something.

A permission error as it appears:

```
getConnection SQL: Communications link failure due to Underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.security.AccessControlException
MESSAGE: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1" "resolve")

STACKTRACE:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1" "resolve") ...
```

Please help me :( I really need it

Comment: Do you wait enough to let it load everything before you try connecting?

Comment: here is some info about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572827/java-applet-java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-net-socketp